# Resize xsane tiny window in Gnome

Tags: gnome, window, sane, wmctrl

I am running Ubuntu 21.10 on a Lenovo Thinkpad with Gnome has my desktop.  When I run xsane my "Advanced Options" window is tiny (10 pixels wide and not much more high) and I cannot seem to resize it.  Thus I do not have access to its functions.

When I move my mouse near edges of the window I do not get the resize pointer. When I right click on the title bar, "Maximize" and "Resize" are greyed out and unavailable.

Running

```
sudo apt purge xsane
sudo apt install xsane
```

did not fix the problem.

When I run `wmctrl -r 'Advanced options HP Color LaserJet MFP M476dw (3DBC02):HP Color LaserJet MFP M476dw (3DBC02)' -e 0,200,300,300,300` I can move the tiny window around but I cannot affect its size.  It remembers this tiny size between sessions so it is being stored in an file somewhere.  In the directory `~/.sane/xsane` there are three settings files: `xsane.rc`:

```
"xsane-version"
"0.999"
"xsane-mode"
1
"tmp-path"
"/tmp/"
"working-directory"
"/home/brett"
"filename"
"/media/Shared/Joelle/page0008.png"
"filetype"
".png"
"cms-function"
1
"cms-intent"
0
"cms-bpc"
0
"image-umask"
95
"directory-umask"
23
"fax-project"
"/home/brett/faxproject"
"fax-command"
"sendfax"
"fax-receiver-option"
"-d"
"fax-postscript-option"
""
"fax-normal-option"
"-l"
"fax-fine-option"
"-m"
"fax-viewer"
"ghostscript"
"fax-width"
14135902
"fax-height"
19462666
"fax-left-offset"
0
"fax-bottom-offset"
0
"fax-fine-mode"
1
"fax-ps-flatedecoded"
1
"e-mail-from"
""
"e-mail-reply-to"
""
"e-mail-smtp-server"
""
"e-mail-smtp-port"
25
"e-mail-authentication"
0
"e-mail-auth-user"
""
"e-mail-auth-pass"
""
"e-mail-pop3-server"
""
"e-mail-pop3-port"
110
"e-mail-project"
"/home/brett/emailproject"
"e-mail-filetype"
".png"
"multipage-project"
"/home/brett/tmp/temp"
"multipage-filetype"
".pdf"
"ocr-command"
"gocr"
"ocr-inputfile-option"
"-i"
"ocr-outputfile-options"
"-o"
"ocr-use-gui-pipe"
0
"ocr-gui-outfd-option"
"-x"
"ocr-progress-keyword"
""
"browser"
"/usr/bin/sensible-browser"
"jpeg-quality"
4587520
"png-compression"
458752
"tiff-zip-compression"
393216
"tiff-compression16_nr"
32773
"tiff-compression8_nr"
7
"tiff-compression1_nr"
3
"save-devprefs-at-exit"
1
"overwrite-warning"
1
"skip-existing-numbers"
1
"save-ps-flatedecoded"
1
"save-pdf-flatedecoded"
1
"save-pnm16-as-ascii"
0
"reduce-16bit-to8bit"
0
"filename-counter-step"
1
"filename-counter-len"
4
"adf-pages-max"
1
"show-range-mode"
6
"tool-tips"
1
"show-histogram"
0
"show-gamma"
1
"show-batch-scan"
0
"show-standard-options"
0
"show-advanced-options"
1
"show-resolution-list"
0
"length-unit"
1664614
"main-window-fixed"
1
"display-icm-profile"
""
"custom-proofing-icm-profile"
""
"working-color-space-icm-profile"
""
"preview-own-cmap"
0
"preview-oversampling"
98304
"preview-gamma"
65536
"preview-gamma-red"
65536
"preview-gamma-green"
65536
"preview-gamma-blue"
65536
"disable-gimp-preview-gamma"
1
"preview-gamma-input-bits"
12
"preview-pipette-range"
3
"gamma"
44348
"gamma-red"
65536
"gamma-green"
65536
"gamma-blue"
65536
"brightness"
869672
"brightness-red"
0
"brightness-green"
0
"brightness-blue"
0
"contrast"
1366627
"contrast-red"
0
"contrast-green"
0
"contrast-blue"
0
"rgb-default"
1
"negative"
0
"auto-enhance-gamma"
1
"preselect-scan-area"
1
"auto-correct-colors"
1
"gtk-update-policy"
1
"medium-nr"
0
"paper-orientation"
0
"preset-area-definitions"
17
"printernr"
0
"printerdefinitions"
1
"printer-name"
"new printer"
"printer-command"
"lp"
"printer-copy-number-option"
"-n"
"printer-lineart-resolution"
300
"printer-grayscale-resolution"
150
"printer-color-resolution"
150
"printer-width"
13316912
"printer-height"
19306193
"printer-left-offset"
229716
"printer-bottom-offset"
229716
"printer-gamma"
65536
"printer-gamma-red"
65536
"printer-gamma-green"
65536
"printer-gamma-blue"
65536
"printer-icm-profile"
""
"printer-ps-flatedecoded"
1
"printer-embed-csa"
1
"printer-embed-crd"
0
"printer-cms-bpc"
0
"preset-area-name"
"DIN A3 port."
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
19462882
"preset-area-height"
27525120
"preset-area-name"
"DIN A3 land."
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
27525120
"preset-area-height"
19462882
"preset-area-name"
"DIN A4 port."
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
13762560
"preset-area-height"
19462882
"preset-area-name"
"DIN A4 land."
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
19462882
"preset-area-height"
13762560
"preset-area-name"
"DIN A5 port."
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
9732096
"preset-area-height"
13762560
"preset-area-name"
"DIN A5 land."
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
13762560
"preset-area-height"
9732096
"preset-area-name"
"13cm x 18cm"
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
8519680
"preset-area-height"
11796480
"preset-area-name"
"18cm x 13cm"
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
11796480
"preset-area-height"
8519680
"preset-area-name"
"10cm x 15cm"
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
6553600
"preset-area-height"
9830400
"preset-area-name"
"15cm x 10cm"
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
9830400
"preset-area-height"
6553600
"preset-area-name"
"9cm x 13cm"
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
5898240
"preset-area-height"
8519680
"preset-area-name"
"13cm x 9cm"
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
8519680
"preset-area-height"
5898240
"preset-area-name"
"legal port."
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
14149222
"preset-area-height"
23304602
"preset-area-name"
"legal land."
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
23304602
"preset-area-height"
14149222
"preset-area-name"
"letter port."
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
14149222
"preset-area-height"
18310758
"preset-area-name"
"letter land."
"preset-area-xoffset"
0
"preset-area-yoffset"
0
"preset-area-width"
18310758
"preset-area-height"
14149222
```

`xsane.mdf` :

```
"MEDIUM_DEFINITIONS"
11
"medium-name"
"Full color range"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
0
"medium-shadow-green"
0
"medium-shadow-blue"
0
"medium-highlight-gray"
6553600
"medium-highlight-red"
6553600
"medium-highlight-green"
6553600
"medium-highlight-blue"
6553600
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
65536
"medium-gamma-green"
65536
"medium-gamma-blue"
65536
"medium-negative"
0
"medium-name"
"Slide"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
0
"medium-shadow-green"
0
"medium-shadow-blue"
0
"medium-highlight-gray"
2621440
"medium-highlight-red"
2621440
"medium-highlight-green"
2621440
"medium-highlight-blue"
2621440
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
65536
"medium-gamma-green"
65536
"medium-gamma-blue"
65536
"medium-negative"
0
"medium-name"
"Standard negative"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
458752
"medium-shadow-green"
65536
"medium-shadow-blue"
0
"medium-highlight-gray"
4325376
"medium-highlight-red"
4325376
"medium-highlight-green"
2162688
"medium-highlight-blue"
1048576
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
65536
"medium-gamma-green"
65536
"medium-gamma-blue"
65536
"medium-negative"
1
"medium-name"
"Agfa negative"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
393216
"medium-shadow-green"
131072
"medium-shadow-blue"
0
"medium-highlight-gray"
2031616
"medium-highlight-red"
3997696
"medium-highlight-green"
1572864
"medium-highlight-blue"
851968
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
65536
"medium-gamma-green"
65536
"medium-gamma-blue"
65536
"medium-negative"
1
"medium-name"
"Agfa negative XRG 200-4"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
786432
"medium-shadow-green"
131072
"medium-shadow-blue"
104857
"medium-highlight-gray"
2293760
"medium-highlight-red"
4030464
"medium-highlight-green"
1409024
"medium-highlight-blue"
950272
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
52428
"medium-gamma-green"
43909
"medium-gamma-blue"
39321
"medium-negative"
1
"medium-name"
"Agfa negative HDC 100"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
229376
"medium-shadow-green"
65536
"medium-shadow-blue"
32768
"medium-highlight-gray"
1736704
"medium-highlight-red"
3506176
"medium-highlight-green"
1441792
"medium-highlight-blue"
1114112
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
51773
"medium-gamma-green"
42598
"medium-gamma-blue"
39321
"medium-negative"
1
"medium-name"
"Fuji negative"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
458752
"medium-shadow-green"
65536
"medium-shadow-blue"
0
"medium-highlight-gray"
2097152
"medium-highlight-red"
4194304
"medium-highlight-green"
2162688
"medium-highlight-blue"
1048576
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
65536
"medium-gamma-green"
65536
"medium-gamma-blue"
65536
"medium-negative"
1
"medium-name"
"Kodak negative"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
589824
"medium-shadow-green"
131072
"medium-shadow-blue"
0
"medium-highlight-gray"
1769472
"medium-highlight-red"
3538944
"medium-highlight-green"
1179648
"medium-highlight-blue"
786432
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
65536
"medium-gamma-green"
65536
"medium-gamma-blue"
65536
"medium-negative"
1
"medium-name"
"Konica negative"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
196608
"medium-shadow-green"
0
"medium-shadow-blue"
0
"medium-highlight-gray"
1638400
"medium-highlight-red"
2490368
"medium-highlight-green"
1376256
"medium-highlight-blue"
917504
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
65536
"medium-gamma-green"
65536
"medium-gamma-blue"
65536
"medium-negative"
1
"medium-name"
"Konica negative VX 100"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
131072
"medium-shadow-green"
0
"medium-shadow-blue"
0
"medium-highlight-gray"
1638400
"medium-highlight-red"
3014656
"medium-highlight-green"
1441792
"medium-highlight-blue"
884736
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
48496
"medium-gamma-green"
36700
"medium-gamma-blue"
34734
"medium-negative"
1
"medium-name"
"Rossmann negative HR 100"
"medium-shadow-gray"
0
"medium-shadow-red"
458752
"medium-shadow-green"
65536
"medium-shadow-blue"
104857
"medium-highlight-gray"
1736704
"medium-highlight-red"
3801088
"medium-highlight-green"
1671168
"medium-highlight-blue"
1245184
"medium-gamma-gray"
65536
"medium-gamma-red"
35389
"medium-gamma-green"
28180
"medium-gamma-blue"
26869
"medium-negative"
1
```

and `WSD:HPColorLaserJetMFPM476dw(3DBC02).drc`:

```
"XSANE_DEVICE_RC"
"WSD:HP Color LaserJet MFP M476dw (3DBC02)"
"xsane-version"
"0.999"
"resolution"
75
"mode"
"Color"
"source"
"Flatbed"
"tl-x"
0
"tl-y"
0
"br-x"
13761367
"br-y"
19459342
"brightness"
0
"contrast"
0
"shadow"
0
"highlight"
6553600
"analog-gamma"
65536
"negative"
0
"xsane-main-window-x-position"
55
"xsane-main-window-y-position"
88
"xsane-main-window-width"
294
"xsane-main-window-height"
570
"xsane-project-window-x-position"
280
"xsane-project-window-y-position"
425
"xsane-standard-options-window-x-position"
414
"xsane-standard-options-window-y-position"
89
"xsane-advanced-options-window-x-position"
448
"xsane-advanced-options-window-y-position"
640
"xsane-histogram-window-x-position"
100
"xsane-histogram-window-y-position"
50
"xsane-gamma-window-x-position"
280
"xsane-gamma-window-y-position"
420
"xsane-batch-window-x-position"
480
"xsane-batch-window-y-position"
420
"xsane-preview-window-x-position"
940
"xsane-preview-window-y-position"
82
"xsane-preview-window-width"
600
"xsane-preview-window-height"
750
"xsane-gamma"
65536
"xsane-gamma-red"
65536
"xsane-gamma-green"
65536
"xsane-gamma-blue"
65536
"xsane-brightness"
0
"xsane-brightness-red"
0
"xsane-brightness-green"
0
"xsane-brightness-blue"
0
"xsane-contrast"
0
"xsane-contrast-red"
0
"xsane-contrast-green"
0
"xsane-contrast-blue"
0
"xsane-lineart-mode"
0
"xsane-threshold"
3276800
"xsane-threshold-min"
0
"xsane-threshold-max"
6553600
"xsane-threshold-multiplier"
65536
"xsane-threshold-offset"
0
"xsane-grayscale-scanmode"
""
"xsane-enhancement-rgb-default"
1
"xsane-negative"
0
"xsane-show-preview"
1
"xsane-enable-color-management"
0
"xsane-scanner-default-color-icm-profile"
""
"xsane-scanner-default-gray-icm-profile"
""
```

This third file has a number of settings that control the position and size of windows.  For example I can move and resize the preview window by changing `xsane-preview-window-x-position`, `xsane-preview-window-y-position`, `xsane-preview-window-width` and `xsane-preview-window-height`.  But the advanced options window only has position data and when I added line

```
"xsane-advanced-options-window-width"
250
```

it was ignored and removed from the file when I quit xsane.  I still don't have an answer but I feel I have made some progress.

Comment: This has been filed as an issue in the SANE project: https://gitlab.com/sane-project/frontend/xsane/-/issues/43

Comment: thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

I was having [another problem in xsane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727191/xsane-not-permitting-width-wider-than-8-267in?noredirect=1&lq=1) where I was only allowed 21cm of width, not the full 8.5in that my HP MFP can do.  In investigating that I found that the scanner was represented by two devices.  `scanimage -L` returned

> device `hpaio:/net/HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M476dw?ip=192.168.0.41' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M476dw all-in-one

> device `airscan:w1:HP Color LaserJet MFP M476dw (3DBC02)' is a WSD HP Color LaserJet MFP M476dw (3DBC02) ip=192.168.0.41, 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7:9ead:97ff:fe5c:7d9, 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7::57f, fdfd:6a08:40d:0:9ead:97ff:fe5c:7d9, fdfd:6a08:40d::57f

And I only had the restricted width problem with the airscan device.  The hpaio device allowed the full range of widths **and** the advanced settings window was regular size again!

I got rid of the airscan device by blacklisting the IP address of my HP MFP in /etc/sane.d/airscan.conf