# xsane not permitting width wider than 8.267in

Tags: ubuntu, scanner, sane

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad with Gnome has my desktop. I have xsane 0.999 installed. My Scanner is an HP Color LaserJet MFP M476dw.  With xsane I used to be able to scan widths up to slightly wider than 8.5in (the maximum that the HP can accommodate).  For a year or more (I don't remember when it started) xsane will only permit a maximum width of 8.267in.  If I try to set the width larger in Standard options, it replaces the value I entered with 8.267.  I cannot drag the width longer than 8.267 in the Preview window.  I do not have access to the Advanced Settings window which is a [known bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679321/resize-xsane-tiny-window-in-gnome).  With vuescan on the same computer with the same scanner I have access to the full width so I think a scanner issue can be ruled out.

Further data:

- `apt update && apt upgrade` did not solve the problem
- I connected an Epson Perfection V500 and xsane gave me 8.5in of available width (and my advanced settings window is OK with that scanner too)
- Another user account on my computer has the same problem with HP scanner and  same success with Epson.
- vuescan does **not** have the same problem but xscanimage and simple-scan both **do** have the same problem.
- On a different computer, also running Ubuntu 22.04, I have exactly the same problem
- I do not have any sane files anywhere in /var/log/

When I run `scanimage -L` There are two devices:

> device `hpaio:/net/HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M476dw?ip=192.168.0.41' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M476dw all-in-one

> device `airscan:w1:HP Color LaserJet MFP M476dw (3DBC02)' is a WSD HP Color LaserJet MFP M476dw (3DBC02) ip=192.168.0.41, 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7:9ead:97ff:fe5c:7d9, 2607:f2c0:ead8:3cf7::57f, fdfd:6a08:40d:0:9ead:97ff:fe5c:7d9, fdfd:6a08:40d::57f

When I use the hpaio device I have access to all 8.5in but when I use the airscan device I do not.

Questions:

- is this a known bug with airscan?
- How can I get rid of the airscan device?
- how can I troubleshoot the cause of this and provide more and better diagnostic information?

Comment: I can only tell that 8.267in ~= 210mm which is the width of an A4 paper: there has to be some relation.

Answer (score 1):

As reported in question, my scanner was showing up as two different devices one using hpaio and the other using airscan.  It was the airscan device which was not working properly.  To disable the airscan device, in /etc/sane.d/airscan.conf I blacklisted the ip address of my HP MFP and now xsane is working fine.  This is at least a quick way to get it working.  This does not answer the question of why airscan was causing the problem.  I have filed this as an issue at [sane-airscan's github](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan/issues) page.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this issue, you can try the following steps:

Check for updates to xsane by running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Check if the issue persists with a different user account on the same computer, or with xsane on a different computer. This will help determine if the issue is specific to your user account or to the xsane installation on your computer.

Check if the issue occurs with other scanners or with other image scanning software, such as vuescan. This will help determine if the issue is specific to your scanner or to xsane.

Check the xsane log files for any error messages or other relevant information. The log files are typically located in the /var/log/xsane directory.

If the issue persists, you can try resetting the xsane settings to their default values by deleting the xsane.rc configuration file. This file is typically located in the ~/.config/xsane directory.

If the issue still persists, you can try uninstalling and reinstalling xsane by running the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt remove xsane
sudo apt install xsane
```

If none of these steps resolve the issue, it is likely that this is a known bug in xsane. You can search for existing bug reports or report the issue on the xsane GitHub page (https://github.com/sane-project/xsane). Providing detailed information about your system, scanner, and xsane installation, along with any relevant log files or error messages, will help the developers diagnose and fix the issue.

Comment: I have done some of your suggestions and added more data to the question